# Using derived type public procedure for array declaration in other derived type

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I need a little help about using derived type public procedure array declaration in other derived type with `DIMENSION` attribute. In my fortran project I have a lot derived types with components whose values are integers and these values are result of numerous calculation. In other module i have a other derived type with integer component which is array. My intention in example code is to declare array with public procedure from another derived type and this is my example:

```
MODULE DERIVED_TYPE

TYPE , PUBLIC :: DT_AA

  INTEGER , PRIVATE :: I_00

  CONTAINS

  PROCEDURE, PUBLIC :: C_I_00 => CALC_DATA_I_00
  PROCEDURE, PUBLIC :: T_I_00 => TAKE_DATA_I_00

END TYPE DT_AA

PRIVATE :: CALC_DATA_I_00
PRIVATE :: TAKE_DATA_I_01

 TYPE( DT_AA ) :: A_DT_AA

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE CALC_DATA_I_00( THIS, INDX )

  CLASS( DT_AA ) :: THIS
  INTEGER, INTENT( IN ) :: INDX

  THIS%I_00 = 4 + INDX

END SUBROUTINE CALC_DATA_I_00

FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_I_00( THIS ) RESULT( RES )

  CLASS( DT_AA ) :: THIS
  INTEGER :: RES

  RES = THIS%I_00

END FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_I_00

END MODULE DERIVED_TYPE

MODULE DERIVED_TYPE_01

USE, NON_INTRINSIC :: DERIVED_TYPE

IMPLICIT NONE

TYPE , PUBLIC :: DT_AB

  INTEGER , DIMENSION( A_DT_AA%T_I_00() ) :: SERT

END TYPE DT_AB

END MODULE DERIVED_TYPE_01

PROGRAM MAIN_PROGRAM

USE, NON_INTRINSIC :: DERIVED_TYPE

IMPLICIT NONE

  CALL A_DT_AA%C_I_00(1)

END PROGRAM MAIN_PROGRAM
```

Afther the end of compiling process I got this message:

Function `TAKE_DATA_I_00` must be PURE

What is wrong with this kind of array declaration with public procedure from derived type?

My IDE is Code::Blocks 17.12 with Gfortran compiler. The version of compiler is: MinGW 6.3.0.

Comment: Show a [mcve]. We need to be able to reproduce the error. Show us where the function is called. It is probably called from a pure procedure. Try to make `TAKE_DATA_I_00` pure.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264729/proper-use-of-the-pure-keyword-fortran

Comment: Show the **actual code** you are compiling. This one gives many other errors. If you make a shorter test case, you **must** test it before posting.

Comment: @VladimirF It is clear for my that using key word `pure` befoure procedure name will make code without compiling error...but my primary motivation in posting question is to learn this kind "tricky" things which are not visible in fortran books or student materials.

Comment: That will not happen without posting an actual [mcve].

Comment: It's still not minimal, but at least this is now the only compilation error, as far as I can see...

Comment: You cannot just use a function result or a variable in an array component definition. More in the link. Even if you make the function pure, the expression must be a **constant expression**. This has nothing to do with the fact that the function is a public type-bound procedure. The point is it is not a constant expression.