# How to call PRNG using sequential seed values?

Tags: random, fortran

Below code was adopted from [prng](http://ckw.phys.ncku.edu.tw/public/pub/Notes/Computers/Lectures/Resources/rsc.anu.edu.au/~harry/COURSES/MATHMETH/node73.html) written in Fortran 77.

```
    double precision function usran(ir)
c
c   this subroutine generates random values between 0.0 and 1.0 using
c   an integer seed
c   it is based on the imsl routine ggubs.
c
c   double precision version
c
    implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
    parameter(da=16807.d0,db=2147483647.d0,dc=2147483648.d0)
    ir=abs(mod(da*ir,db)+0.5d0)
    usran=dfloat(ir)/dc
    return
    end
```

It seems to me that `ir` is the seed input which is a reassigned integer, ideally it's returns a random number in between 0 and 1, which is then used as the next seed value. But I don't see how it works?

I mean if I have an initial random value as my `seed`, then input `usran(seed)` returns a value in (0,1), then how to call the next value in the current sequence?

I can't think of a more specific title for this thread.

Comment: I don't quite follow your question.  Are you aware that `seed`, through the argument `ir` will also be modified?  That is, the function has an effect on what is passed, not just having a result.

Comment: I'm just confused about how is the returned value used as the next seed value? I can see that it's modified, for a quick example, if my initial `seed = 12345`, then `ir =abs(mod(12345*da,db)+0.5)`, and `usran(seed)` returns `ir/dc`, I get your point that we now have a new ir value, but how does it contribute to a new seed value, don't you still need to evaluate `usran(seed)` in order to obtain the next value?

Comment: in another word, how is this sequential? if it's not sequential then what makes it a PRNG?

Comment: What do you mean by "sequential"?  You call the function with a seed and get back a "random number" and a new seed.  You pass this new seed to get the next value and yet another new seed.  Perhaps you could show us the context of how you expect to use the generator in a main program?  If that's off it gives us something to "correct".

Comment: @francescalus, I guess I'm confused about how to pass the new seed -`ir` back to `usran()` since this functional subroutine only returns usran which is a real number in (0,1). I guess one way is to compute usran*dc after where usran(seed) is called in the program and use it as the new seed?

Comment: That's my earlier comment: `a=usran(seed)` modifies `seed`, so you can `a=usran(seed); b=usran(seed)` and have `a` and `b` two of the sequence.  `usran` is not pure.

Comment: That is exactly why I rewrote the PRNG I am using to subroutines. The side effects in functions are simply confusing.

Comment: @Vladimir what exact side effects you see in this particular function?

Comment: Well, I meant the changing of the input argument. Maybe *side effect* is not the right word in this case. Often the state is a saved global (module) variable and then *side effect* is the correct term.

Comment: I still don't get your "side effect", but I see how this function works now, by adding `integer, intent(inout) :: ir`, if I hold my `seed` value a constant, and run `usran(seed)` multiple times in the main program, it returns a different values with a different seed value each time. I don't know why I didn't see the case at the beginning.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect

Comment: @francescalus, are you or \@VladmirF planning to make this comments / conversation into a proper answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean if I have an initial random value as my `seed`, then input
>   `usran(seed)` returns a value in (0,1), then how to call the next value
>   in the current sequence?

As @francescalus and @Vladmir F commented, this function has a [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). From Wikipedia:

> In computer science, a function or expression is said to have a side
>   effect if it modifies some state outside its scope or has an
>   observable interaction with its calling functions or the outside world
>   besides returning a value. For example, a particular function might
>   modify a global variable or static variable, modify one of its
>   arguments, raise an exception, write data to a display or file, read
>   data from a keyboard or a file, or call other side-effecting
>   functions. In the presence of side effects, a program's behaviour may
>   depend on history; that is, the order of evaluation matters.
>   Understanding and debugging a function with side effects requires
>   knowledge about the context and its possible histories. A
>   function or expression without side effects is said to be pure.

In the specific case of your function, besides returning a random number, it changes the value of its argument with `ir=abs(mod(da*ir,db)+0.5d0)`. So each time you call it again with the same variable as argument, `ir` will be passed with a different value and thus a different random number will be generated.

"[Purity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264729/proper-use-of-the-pure-keyword-fortran)" of procedures plays an imporant role in Fortran context because the posibility of side-effects prevents the compiler to do some code optimizations. A subroutine can still be considered pure if its only side-effect is to modify specific arguments.

But there are cases that, by the very nature of the procedure, side-effects can't be avoided and sometimes even are desired. Gathering random numbers is an example, also are doing I/O, stopping the code or configuring a module.